# How to fetch floating no in offchain worker?

Tags: storage, api, offchain-storage, floating-point-math

I want to fetch the floating value in offchain worker. I'm using `lite_json` for http request.

```json
Api data: {
"price": 0.5
}
```

To fetch and store this price from api. I'm defining a struct:

```rust
pub struct data {
   price: ?
}
```

Ques 1: here what would be the type of price?

Here is the code for fetching data:

```rust
let obj_price = match obj.clone() {
                JsonValue::Object(obj_data) => {
                    let (_, v) = obj_data.into_iter().find(|(k, _)| k.iter().copied().eq("price".chars()))?;
                    match v {
                        JsonValue::Number(val) => val,
                        _ => return None,
                    }
                },
                _ => return None,
            };

            let Price = obj_price; // ??
```

Ques2: How to convert obj_price to the type that we defined in the struct?

Or we can't fetch floating no. at all using `lite_json`?